# jQuery mobile 1.2.0 Alpha 1 autodividersSelector

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to divide a jQuery mobile list depending on an attribute in each li element.

```
$("#mylistview").listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function ( li ) {
        var out = $('li').attr('attr_name');
        return out;
    }
});
```

But it creates the list divider only for the 1st list item attribute. I'm using listview(refresh) each time I insert a new li.

What I don't understand is if I need to call the function I pasted here before creating the list, after or for each element. I think I've tried each of those but maybe I'm not doing it right.

Is that because the 1.2.0 is still alpha? I thought this function was working now
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Thanks to whoever will be able/willing to answer.

Comment: 1.2.0 is released now. Try it with the release version and let us know.

Comment: @RaymondCamden Thanks for the answer.
It's still not working for me, but I just noticed I was not using data-role in each li. Added it but still not working.

Comment: No sorry data-role="list-divider" is for manually creating list dividers.
With the autodivide shouldn't I be able to do it automatically using an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault:
the right code is

```
$("#mylistview").listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function ( li ) {
        var out = li.attr('attr_name'); //HERE THE CHANGE
        return out;
    }
});
```

Thanks anyway for the reply.