# Autodividers for list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating a lits of items including first and last names.  The list is sorted by last name.  How do you create autodividers that will dividing the list items by last name?

```
<div class="listWrap">
    <div id="userFilter">
        <ul id="usersListView" data-bind="template: {name: 'usersListTemplate', foreach: users}" data-role="listview" data-filter="false" data-filter-placeholder="enter a colleague's name...">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script id="usersListTemplate" type="text/html">
        <li data-theme="h" data-bind="click: $parent.UserInfo" class="clickableRow">
            <table>
                <tr class="colleague">
                    <td>
                        <table>                         
                            <tr><td><span style="font-size:20px" class="firstname_" data-bind="text: firstname"></span>&nbsp;<span style="font-size:20px" data-bind="text: lastname"></span></td></tr>
                            <tr><td><a data-bind="text: email, attr: { href: 'mailto:'+email()}, click: $parent.alwaysTrue, clickBubble: false"></a></td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: What are "autodividers"?

Comment: @Diodeus http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Comment: The link you've posted clearly suggests using `autodividersSelector` for that. Is it not working for you?

Comment: @IliaG it is not working

Comment: probably [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693706/jquery-mobile-1-2-0-alpha-1-autodividersselector) helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do to use a *custom* text for the autodividers.

- You need to add `data-autodividers="true"` to the `ul`
- You need to specify a `autodividersSelector` function that outputs
  the text for the autodivider
- You need to refresh the listview

For example given the following simplified version of your markup

```
  <div data-role="page" id="pageAutoDiv">
    <div data-role="header"><h3>Header</h3></div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-autodividers="true" id="usersListView" data-role="listview">
        <li> <span class="firstname_">Francisca  </span>&nbsp;<span  class="lastname" data-bind="text: lastname">Fidler</span></li>
        <li><span class="firstname_">Jolie  </span>&nbsp;<span class="lastname" data-bind="text: lastname">Jarnagin</span></li>
        <li><span class="firstname_">Quiana </span>&nbsp;<span class="lastname" data-bind="text: lastname">Quiroz</span></li>
      </ul>      
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div>
  </div>
```

You can use the following JavaScript to create autodividers using the lastname

```
$('#pageAutoDiv').bind('pageshow', function () {
    $('#usersListView').listview({
        autodividers: true,
        autodividersSelector: function (li) {
            return $(li).find('.lastname').text();
        }
    });

    $('#usersListView').listview('refresh');
});
```

Here's a link to a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/irixat/1/edit) (using a little more of your markup)