# dynamic alphabetical dividers

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

How do you create alphabetical dividers for a list created by an observable array?  I want the list to be divided by lastname.  It is already sorted, it just needs the dividers.

The list is created here:

```
function GetUsersByLocation(){

        var url = 'http://localhost/Service.svc/GetUsersByLocation/'+localStorage.CurrentLocationId;

        var jqxhr =
        $.getJSON(url,
        function (data) 
        { 
            userViewModel.clearUsers();
            $.each(data.GetUsersByLocationResult, function (key, val) {
                userViewModel.addUser(val.FirstName, val.LastName);
            });
            ko.applyBindings(userViewModel, document.getElementById("usersListView"));
        })
         .success(function () { $('#usersListView').listview('refresh'); })
    }
```

And implemented here:

```
<div>
    <ul id="usersListView" data-bind="template: {name: 'usersListTemplate', foreach: users}" data-role="listview" data-filter="false" data-filter-placeholder="enter a colleague's name..."></ul>
</div>
<script id="usersListTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li><a href="javascript: void(0)">
        <table>
            <tr class="colleague">
                <td>
                    <table>                         
                        <tr><td><span class="firstname_" data-bind="text: firstname"></span>&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: lastname"></span></td></tr>
                    </table></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like one of your [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404876/autodividers-for-list)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 1.2, you can add the data-autodividers="true" attribute, as seen [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html). If necessary, you can set the autodividersSelector option on the listview to specify custom selector.

> A listview can be configured to automatically generate dividers for its items. This is done by adding a data-autodividers="true" attribute to any listview.